# Optimize rendering large of objects in p5js

Tags: javascript, graphics, 3d, p5.js

I am trying to create a scene using p5.js that creates many different objects in 3d space. It works fine for a small number of objects but slows down really badly for thousands of objects.  The objects and their relative positions will remain the same so I was wondering if it's possible to render once and then only rotate the view angle or control with the mouse without having to draw every single object again for every single draw iteration.  I have tired noloop and creating the objects outside the draw loop and the perspective change within the draw loop but the scene remains static.  Many thanks in advance!

```
var Sz = 300;
var N = 1000;
var x = [];
var y = [];
var z = [];
// noprotect

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  background(0);

  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = random(-Sz, Sz);
    y[i] = random(-Sz, Sz);
    z[i] = random(-Sz, Sz);
  }
}

function draw() {
  background(0, 0, 0);
  //translate(0,0,-100);
  rotateY(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateX(frameCount * 0.01);
  rotateZ(frameCount * 0.01);
  orbitControl();

  for (var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    push();
    translate(x[i], y[i], z[i]);
    R = 255 * abs(x[i] / max(x));
    G = 255 * abs(y[i] / max(y));
    B = 255 * abs(z[i] / max(z));
    stroke(R, G, B);
    sphere(Sz / 50, 8);
    pop();
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately p5.js does not currently support it, but I think [instanced geometry](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-instanced-drawing.html) would give you the performance gains you are looking for. Basically this lets you bind arrays to shader attributes such that the shader program will be run once per entry in these arrays. If you're not familiar with the basics of shader programming this may be over your head, in which case I apologize. I'm not able to explain this in the context of a SO question. I've been meaning to write a tutorial on this.

Comment: Super early days preview of some instanced geometry support: https://openprocessing.org/sketch/1487929

Comment: @PaulWheeler    Many thanks for this,  as you said it is currently a bit over my head but I'm working at it.

Answer (score 0):

You can start looking into Three.js or other WebGL libraries if you need this kind of control or optimization.